# ERROR exporting Eclipse Plug-In

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to export an Eclipse Plgug-In in Eclipse Oxygen, but I get the following errors (only 2):

[image]

The error is in one of my Java Classes, emitter1, when I use the xerces import and then the Base64 Object below, but when I compile the plug-in in the IDE in runs with no errors,

Here's an image of my projects tree:

[image]

The import and the object are being used, like I said, in the emitter1 class,

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to solve it?

Maybe I can't use referenced libraries in plug-in projects, or I have to add them in a different way? What I did was: Right-Click on Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Add External Jars, and added xerces jar

Thank you!

Alexandre Jacinto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use external jars in a plugin. You can only reference code in other plugins or jars which you include as part of your plugin and add to the `Bundle-Classpath` in the MANIFEST.MF (and also update the build.properties to include the jars in the build).

An example `Bundle-Classpath` from one of my plug-ins:

```
Bundle-ClassPath: .,
 lib/jogg-0.0.7.jar,
 lib/jorbis-0.0.15.jar,
 lib/vorbisspi1.0.2.jar
```

The `.` is your normal code and the other entries are jars in a `lib` directory in the plugin project.

The `build.properties` would include

```
bin.includes = ....... other things
               .,\
               lib/jogg-0.0.7.jar,\
               lib/jorbis-0.0.15.jar,\
               lib/vorbisspi1.0.2.jar
```

If you use the normal plugin.xml/MANIFEST.MF/build.properties editor you define the bundle classpath on the 'Runtime' tab in the 'Classpath' section and the build.properties on the build.properties tab.

Unfortunately Eclipse doesn't check any of this when you test your plugin within Eclipse. The errors only appear in exported plugins and RCPs.

Comment: So what I need to do is include the jar files in the Bundle-Classpath in the MANIFESF-MF (I can't find the Bundle-Classpath) and then update the build.properties to include the jars in the build? Do I remove the external jars from the Java Build Path?

Comment: Yes you remove the external jars from the build path. If you use the normal plugin.xml/MANIFEST.MF/build.properties editor you define the bundle classpath on the 'Runtime' tab in the 'Classpath' section and the build.properties on the build.properties tab.